# Excel issue - Link a cell to the number of documents in a file

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I am trying to get an excel spreadsheet to update when a document is inserted into a file.

For example I have a folder called day diary.
Every few days I will insert a word document or PDF document into this folder.
I would like for the excel spreadsheet to acknowledge that a document has been put in the file.

Is this possible?

VBA welcome, however I have no experience in it. (Willing to learn a bit)

Thanks for your time!

I'm getting some negative feedback towards my laziness.
Fair enough. I usually just use YouTube for my answers.
It was not my intention to get a script written for me. Just if what I was asking was possible or if a certain function exists. I am more then capable of doing the leg work. I just don't know where to begin.

If anyone can offer direction then I will keep updating this page with my progress. I'm sure it could help someone else looking for the same problem further down the line.

Comment: Do you think we're here to do your work for you? I have voted to close. However, if you [edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/1106410/edit) and show what you've tried, then I'll remove my vote

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

This VBA script could help you:

```
Public Sub fileIndexer()
    'declaration of variables
    sheetname = "Sheet1"
    directory = "C:\users\johnsmith\documents"
    firstRow = 1
    dataColumn = 1
    'end of declaration of variables
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wks = wkb.Sheets(sheetname)
    wks.Columns(dataColumn).Clear
    myRow = firstRow
    myPath = Dir(directory)
    While (myPath <> "")
        wks.Cells(myRow, dataColumn) = myPath
        myRow = myRow + 1
        myPath = Dir
    Wend
    wks.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Open VBA/Macros with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, under *ThisWorkbook* insert a new module and paste the code on the right side.

Execute it clicking the green triangle.

You can run it also step by step by clicking on the first line and then go through each step pressing <kbd>F8</kbd>.

There is a section called `declaration of variables`where you have to put your data ( name of sheet and directory to be listed).